# How to get the first row which exceeds a specific amount in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table which contains the following data:

| ID | Amount | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 | 2021-05-01 |
| 2 | 100 | 2021-05-03 |
| 3 | 300 | 2021-05-06 |

I need to get the first record which exceeds a specific amount, such as the following examples:

- If specific amount is 500, we return ID 1
- If specific amount is 550, we return ID 2
- If specific amount if 600, we return ID 2
- If specific amount > 600, we return ID 3

How can this be achieved using a MySQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a cumulative sum and some filtering:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(amount) over (order by date) as running_amount
      from t
     ) t
where running_amount >= @threshold and
      (running_amount - amount) < @threshold;
```